# Default login credentials are not working Ubuntu 20.04 on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: login

I installed ubuntu 20.04 64 bit on my Raspberry Pi 4, after boot process at the login screen, username and password won't work. what to do? I am unable to login.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you installed the correct Ubuntu version from [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) and followed the tutorial [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#1-overview), and you are sure that installation is not corrupted, you could try to reset the password.

1. mount the sd in rw mode on a linux system
2. chroot to the mounted sd
3. use the `passwd` command to change the user password
4. reboot

OR

1. mount the sd in rw mode on a linux system
2. edit the password file i.e.: `/mnt/etc/shadow`

### Editing the password file:

You'll find a row containig

```
<your_user>:<hashed_password>:14589::::::
```

like

```
pippo:$1$9fsdljkel!nFDSfdfasL.blablabla1!54M:14589::::::
```

just remove "$1$9fsdljkel!nFDSfdfasL.blablabla1!54M" and obtain

```
pippo::14589::::::
```

This way user "pippo" will have a blank password.
Don't try to modify `root` user because he can't login directly on Ubuntu OS.
Once logged on the system just set the password for that user and check if it is set correctly.

Comment: Solved. Thankyou very much. changed passwd file and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Directly after 1st boot the username and password (ubuntu/ubuntu) won't work, even though the login screen is shown. After waiting until the cloud-init + SSH-key creation messages are shown it will be possible to log in with the default credentials (ubuntu/ubuntu). This may take a few minutes depending on what model of Pi is being used.

Answer (score 1):

ubuntu 20.04.2 or greater installed in Raspberry Pi
login > ubuntu
password > ubuntu

documentation > https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#4-boot-ubuntu-server