# Cannot login in Ubuntu server 20.04 with RaspberryPi 4

Tags: apt, server, login

Have followed instructions (endlessly) to load 20.04 (server only, no desktop or gui) on a RP4 w/8GBs of ram. Always the same result. On installation (first boot) I go into an endless loop at login.

Have searched the web for solutions and nothing seems to work except that I see this is a common situation.

I’m asked for `ubuntu login:`. I enter `ubuntu`. I’m asked for password. I enter `ubuntu`. I’m answered with

```
Login incorrect
ubuntu login:
```

If I could get past the loop I’d be ready for sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade. But the loop, the endless loop, it won’t go away ....

Comment: What do you mean by endless loop? What problem do you face? You just need to enter your username, press enter, enter your password (the password won't show up for security reasons), and press enter

Comment: I WISH it was that simple. I’ve done what you say over and over again and the login doesn’t take. This is well documented on the web as a problem for users who have installed the system. Fixes are not documented for users who encounter this during installation. ... an endless loop means I’m asked for ubuntu login:. I enter ubuntu. I’m asked for password. I enter ubuntu. I’m answered with Login incorrect ubuntu login: THAT is the endless loop

Comment: I would mount the SD card on another system and change the ubuntu password there: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235634/default-login-credentials-are-not-working-ubuntu-20-04-on-raspberry-pi-4

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Thank you Wayne .... your answer got me part way there.

1. I used a new SD card. Don’t know if that made a difference or not.
2. I connected to internet through Ethernet during the installation process. THAT made a huge difference. Instructions in the Ubuntu Server for Raspberry Pi tutorial say to use Ethernet OR to edit net-config for wireless. I initially went for the edit net-config option and the login loop was endless. Enter login name, enter password, over and over again.
3. Connected to Ethernet as previously described, login worked as it should, and all is fine.
4. The tutorial instructions probably need to be updated. Or maybe it was just my bad luck.

Hope this is helpful for someone .....